# ReplayKit Live Data Processing

Tags: ios, broadcast, replaykit

I'm currently trying to create an app which makes use of the ReplayKit Live feature to broadcast the iPhone screen to a service which I want to provide by myself (basically something similar to what Teamviewer QuickSupport is doing).

I do know how to create the extension by itself, however, I do not have enough information on how the best way would be to process these informations and upload it to the backend. I did search a lot but without any success:

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/52434 - This is basically the same question I have but sadly without any answer

So my question is: Does anyone have any insight on how the video sample buffer (made available by `processSampleBuffer`) could be processed and uploaded on a backend without inducing large delays?